# Angular , how to apply an attribute directive to an element in index.html

Tags: angular, directive

I have some script tags of asynchronous javascript libraries in index.html and I want to apply them an attribute directive to control their "activation" by changing the type attribute from "text/plain" to "text/javascript" when the user provides the cookie consent. The directive seems to be never reached by angular maybe because it is outside the angular zone, in fact logs in the constructor and in the callback of subscription function are never printed in console and the directive becomes useless.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appLoadOnConsent]'
})
export class LoadOnConsentDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private statusChangeSubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(
    private ccService: NgcCookieConsentService,
    el: ElementRef
  ) {
    // never printed
    console.log(el);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.statusChangeSubscription = this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe(
      (event: NgcStatusChangeEvent) => {
        // never printed
        console.log('cookie status change', event);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.statusChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

in index.html

```
<head>
  ....
  // library 1
  <script type="text/plain" appLoadOnConsent async defer src="https://external.library1.js"></script>
  // library 2
  <script type="text/plain" appLoadOnConsent async defer src="https://external.library2.js"></script>
</head>
....
```

How can I reach my goal? Are there better ways to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could try waiting for consent before loading the package.

So let's say you have a handler for consent

```
handleConsent(consentGiven: boolean): void {
    if (consentGiven) {
        console.log('consent was given');
    }
}
```

Now I do not know if this will work, but I would try this. Do a [dynamic import](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import).

So it could looks something like this:

```
handleConsent(consentGiven: boolean): void {
    if (consentGiven) {
        import('https://external.library1.js')
        .then((module) => {
            module.default();
            module.doStuff();
        });
    }
}
```

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Angular won't let you handle any scripts. Please look [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903#issuecomment-383565320) to how others loaded scripts dynamicaly.

Comment: I know the techniques in the post you linked and probably I will implement those but still remaining my doubt, apply a directive on an element in index.html does not work because I am outside the angular zone or because Angular prevents any actions on tag script?

Comment: I think angular prevents script tags in templates. I tried it on stackblitz within a <ng-container *ngIf="allowScripts">. Anything other then <script> works.

Comment: I tried to apply the directive to a div element in index.html but doesn't work, it works instead if you put that div in in the app.component.html so I think that everything is outside of the AppComponent is outside the angular zone and it's not possible to apply them anything

Comment: Have you tried to declare your directive in the bootstrap: [] element of your AppModule?

Comment: You're right, but I solve creating a component inside the app component which manages script tags adding them dinamically on cookie consent